# Error while publishing Apps to Windows 10 Store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp

I uploaded my app package to windows 10 store. It went for the certifications and then it showed me the errors shown in the image.
[image]

I have tried it again my adding the BadgeLogo again, but it again shows same errors. I uploaded all the assets images in png format, but it only show error in BadgeLogo.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you examined the ARGB values of the image?

Comment: What do you mean by examining? I made all images in photoshop in png format and uploaded that in manifest visual assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem in my last package published.

As mentioned, the badge logo should be transparent OR white color..
You can achieve that by changing the color of your badge logos to the White color `(#fff) (RGB: 255,255,255)` ..

Good Luck!

Comment: Well thankx alot. If I ask you one thing more that is badge logo necessary for a simple static app? Because visual studio doesn't show error if there is no badge logo.

Comment: it's not required while you disabling the Toast/ Badges (lock screen) capabilities from package.manifest settings :)